# Being $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ independent random variables, and being. $ f(x_{1};\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{1+\theta}}$ where $x>0$ , $\theta >2$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Being $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ independent random variables, and being.

$ \displaystyle f(x_{1};\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{1+\theta}}$  where $x>0$  , $\theta >2$

Is created a new function:

$\displaystyle U_{n}=(n-2)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$

Find the values $c$ and $d$ that:

$\frac{U_{n}-c}{d}  \sim N(0,1)$

I don´t know how to start this. Most of the asympotic theory exercises that I solved I used theorems like Slutsty or Great law of weak numbers but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Consider using moment or characteristic functions.

Comment: How do I find the characteristic function of $U_{n}$?

Comment: I would write $U_n=\frac{n}{n-2}\overline{X}_n$ and use the fact that $$\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X}_n-\mu\right)\longrightarrow _d \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$$ where $\mu=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\theta x\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)^{\theta+1}}$ and $\sigma^2=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\theta (x-\mu)^2 \mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)^{\theta+1}}$.

Comment: $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty)} \frac{n}{n-1}=1$.
Then, using that $\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X}_n-\mu\right)\longrightarrow _d \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$

Is it true that $\overline X_{n} \rightarrow_{d} N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$

How can I continue?